# Always property is missing in type { }

Tags: typescript

Trying to practice typescript and all types was going good except the following example when im trying to assign the exported interface from FactionKicks to be used in TornRequester .

file index.ts

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { FactionKicks, MemberShipNews } from "./FactionKicks";

const properties = ["user", "property", "faction", "company", "market", "torn"];

class TornRequester {
  data: MemberShipNews = {};

  constructor(public prop: string) {}

  getProp() {
    return axios
      .get(
        "https://api.torn.com/faction/26043?selections=membershipnews&key=ABhLYU48Ok7M10CV"
      )
      .then(res => {
        const d: MemberShipNews = res.data;
        this.data = d;
        const f = new FactionKicks(this.data);
        f.print;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}

const req = new TornRequester(properties[2]);

req.getProp();
```

and FactionKicks.ts

```js
export interface MemberShipNews {
  membershipnews: {
    id: {
      timestamp: number;
      news: string;
    };
  };
}

export class FactionKicks {
  constructor(public news: MemberShipNews) {}
  get print(): void {
    return console.log(this.news);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned `{}` to a type that requires a `membershipnews` property. Typescript is telling you that you cannot do that.

What I think you want is a way to say that this data has not yet loaded. TO achive that, make the type of `data` a union with `null`.

```
data: MemberShipNews | null = null;
```

Now `this.data` has two possible types. `null` before the axios request is finished, or `MemberShipNews` which should be the results of your axios request.

Elsewhere in your code, you can test if the data is available like so:

```
if (this.data) {
  console.log(this.data.membershipnews)
} else {
  console.log('this.data is not yet loaded')
}
```